# Python - Interger / Variable issues. New programmer

Tags: python, variables, integer

i am extremely new to the coding world. Started Python last week and had been following the website and video titled "Automate the boring stuff" and some other websites that ive been following along at the same time. I only made it to lesson five because i started writing up my own program to see what i learned so far.

Also, i had tried to find help about my issue here and on other forums but i may be phrasing my question wrong. If you have any tips about phrasing or how to phrase these that would be a lot of help too. Anyways... here is the code ive been working along with in automate the boring stuff.

---

```
name = "Walter"
age = 26

print("Who am i speaking with")


name = input()


if name == "Walter":
    print("how old is Walter?")
else:
    print("SHUT THE FUCK UP DONNY.")

#After printing "Walter" the number 26 appears under the next question.
#Who am i speaking with
#Walter
#how old is Walter?
#26
#Numbers should only print after i input the interger in the next line.


age = int(input(age))


if age == 26:
    print("Hello Walter")
elif age <= 25:
    print("You are not Walter")
elif age >= 27:
    print("You must be a vampire")
```

---

ive been using pythontutor.com to help me understand the code. Since the global frame variable and/or integer 26 is at the top, the line "if age == 26:" automatically prints the integer. I cant figure out why. Python is supposed to follow the lines in order. obviously im missing something. i tried changing the order of everything or changing the variables/strings. I watched the video and reread everything but im not sure if i understand everything.

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter2/#calibre_link-1913

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from this line:

```
age = int(input(age))
```

The parameter to `input` is the prompt it should print when reading from the keyboard.  So, that's what prints the "26".  It then waits for you to enter another number.  That new number then gets stored in `age`, replacing the old value.  The `if` statement will thus test the NEW value of `age`.

So, you could replace

```
print("Who am i speaking with")


name = input()
```

with

```
name = input("Who am i speaking with?")
```

If you don't want that second line to print 26, then remove the parameter:

```
age = int(input())
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter passed to `input` is printed on screen, if you use `input(">>")` you'll see `>>`. Remove `age` from `int(input(age))` and use just `int(input())`

Answer (score 1):

I ran your program and found that `26` is printed from the line `age = int(input(age))`, not `if age == 26`. This happens because when you put a value as a parameter in `input()`, it uses that as a prompt in front of where you type. This means that you could type your input after the prompt, but the prompt itself cannot be erased, you have to change the value entered in `input()`.

Here's what I would change your code to:

```
name = "Walter"
age = 26

print("Who am i speaking with")


name = input()


if name == "Walter":
    print("how old is Walter?")
else:
    print("SHUT THE FUCK UP DONNY.")

#After printing "Walter" the number 26 appears under the next question.
#Who am i speaking with
#Walter
#how old is Walter?
#26
#Numbers should only print after i input the interger in the next line.


age = int(input()) # took out age variable
print(age) # prints age entered


if age == 26:
    print("Hello Walter")
elif age <= 25:
    print("You are not Walter")
elif age >= 27:
    print("You must be a vampire")
```

If you want a prompt for entering age such as "Enter your age: ", you would replace `age = int(input())` with `age = int(input('Enter your age: '))`

More info on `input()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp)

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: It really does! i played around and searched for hours on this. Thank you Thomas!